# Core Data Relationships Help ... should be basic i hope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

So i have two relationships between two entities in core data, titled "number" and "info."  I give the user their number and when i do that i would like for them in return to give me their name so that I can tie it to their specific number. I cannot seem to get the code right to do this. So far the closest that i think i have gotten is this:

```
        for (UserNumber *pinNumbers in [entryView pinNumberArray]) {
            if ([numberString isEqualToString:pinNumbers.PIN]) {
                UserInfo *info = pinNumbers.info;   
                [info setName:nameField.text];  
            }
        }
```

where i loop through the number that they have entered and if i can find it inside the array that core data populates i would then like them to assign their name to this. Could anyone show me an example of how this might be done?

Thanks.

Comment: So, is your intent to avoid the loop and just have Core Data return a UserInfo instance associated with a UserNumber instance? If so, look at creating an NSPredicate in your Fetch...

Comment: Well ultimately my intent is to link the number that they are given to their name. Pretty much I would like to create a really simple row containing two values number and name. but i do not know how to tie their name to their unique number. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is something like this:

[image]

such that there is a one-to-one bidirectional relationship between UserNumber and UserInfo, then it seems that you could probably have 'number' be an attribute of UserInfo and simplify your model. (Is it the case that 'number' is unique for each UserInfo?)

But, going with your current model, assuming one-to-one relationship, something like this should work - provided that UserNumber has a 'number' attribute and to-one relationship called 'info' that points to a UserInfo.

```
// Search for UserNumber that has NSString* pinCode as value for attribute PIN
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserNumber"
                         inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PIN contains[cd] %@", pinCode];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *items = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];

// UserNumber with matching PIN was found, so set name of associated UserInfo.
if ( [items count] == 1 )
    {   
    UserNumber *userNumber = [items lastObject];
    UserInfo *userInfo = [userNumber info];
    [userInfo setName:nameField.text];
    }
```

Note that items should have either zero or one element. If one, then that first element is the matching UserNumber. By traversing that UserNumber's 'info' relationship, you will be able to get corresponding UserInfo - provided that you've properly created the link previously.

**Update**

In writing this code snippet, I realized that I don't actually understand what you are trying to do ;-). Is this part of a registration process? If so, then you would need to deal with creation of UserInfo object *and* relationship between objects. Or is this part of logging in? Or part of editing user info? Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is just what i need, I don't have any NSPredicate in my code at the moment and I'm hoping thats the trick. Cant wait to go home a try it out, quick question though, the intValue, what is that?

Comment: Numbers are stored in Core Data (and elsewhere) as NSNumber objects. To get at the actual value of an NSNumber you need to use of many accessors (e.g., intValue, floatValue, doubleValue, etc.). The same is true in reverse: when you go to store a number in Core Data, you will need to create an NSNumber from an int or NSInteger or NSUInteger or ... Check out class reference docs for NSNumber.

Comment: Could i use this:      UserInfo *info = pinNumbers.info; [info setName:nameField.text];   To traverse UserNumers info relationship?

Comment: I've gone through a bunch of things on google and i think that i really don't need to have2 entities for what i want. I think i can just use one. I read somewhere that NSManangedObjectContext can be though of as a row in databases, and that helps out a ton. However if i have an entity that has two attributes i cant figure out how to target the PIN on each one and change the name for the specific NSManagedObjectContext. Thank you so much for you help though. If you feel like giving me some more direction could you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053213/core-data-edit-attributes